# How to process video? which I am getting from the team-recording bot

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

My Team-recording bot code is running in azure Kubernetes service. The code is written in the .netframework language. The bot can join the team meeting and it is recording the meeting and saving the files in audio(wav) format to local in a .zip file. I want to process the video files to local in a .zip file. Right now we have AudioProcessor class to get the audio files:`        public BotMediaStream(
ILocalMediaSession mediaSession,
string callId,
IGraphLogger logger,
IEventPublisher eventPublisher,
IAzureSettings settings
)
: base(logger)
{
ArgumentVerifier.ThrowOnNullArgument(mediaSession, nameof(mediaSession));
ArgumentVerifier.ThrowOnNullArgument(logger, nameof(logger));
ArgumentVerifier.ThrowOnNullArgument(settings, nameof(settings));

```
            this.participants = new List<IParticipant>();

            _eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
            _callId = callId;
            _mediaStream = new MediaStream(
                settings,
                logger,
                mediaSession.MediaSessionId.ToString()
            );

            // Subscribe to the audio media.
            this._audioSocket = mediaSession.AudioSocket;
            if (this._audioSocket == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("A mediaSession needs to have at least an audioSocket");
            }

            this._audioSocket.AudioMediaReceived += this.OnAudioMediaReceived;


            this.videoSockets = mediaSession.VideoSockets?.ToList();
            if (this.videoSockets?.Any() == true)
            {
                this.videoSockets.ForEach(videoSocket => videoSocket.VideoMediaReceived += this.OnVideoMediaReceived);
            }

            // Subscribe to the VBSS media.
            this.vbssSocket = mediaSession.VbssSocket;
            if (this.vbssSocket != null)
            {
                mediaSession.VbssSocket.VideoMediaReceived += this.OnVbssMediaReceived;
            }

        }

`

     private ILocalMediaSession CreateLocalMediaSession(Guid mediaSessionId = default)
        {
            try
            {
                // create media session object, this is needed to establish call connections
                var videoSocketSettings = new List<VideoSocketSettings>();

                // create the receive only sockets settings for the multiview support
                for (int i = 0; i < SampleConstants.NumberOfMultiviewSockets; i++)
                {
                    videoSocketSettings.Add(new VideoSocketSettings
                    {
                        StreamDirections = StreamDirection.Recvonly,
                        ReceiveColorFormat = VideoColorFormat.H264,
                    });
                }

                // Create the VBSS socket settings
                var vbssSocketSettings = new VideoSocketSettings
                {
                    StreamDirections = StreamDirection.Recvonly,
                    ReceiveColorFormat = VideoColorFormat.H264,
                    MediaType = MediaType.Vbss,
                    SupportedSendVideoFormats = new List<VideoFormat>
                {
                    // fps 1.875 is required for h264 in vbss scenario.
                    VideoFormat.H264_1920x1080_1_875Fps,
                },
                };

                // create media session object, this is needed to establish call connections
                var mediaSession = this.Client.CreateMediaSession(
                    new AudioSocketSettings
                    {
                        StreamDirections = StreamDirection.Recvonly,
                        SupportedAudioFormat = AudioFormat.Pcm16K,
                    },
                    videoSocketSettings,
                    vbssSocketSettings,
                    mediaSessionId: mediaSessionId);
                return mediaSession;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.Log(System.Diagnostics.TraceLevel.Error, e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Here audio is getting processed from team-recording-bot

```
AudioProcessor code: `// ***********************************************************************
// Assembly         : RecordingBot.Services
// Author           : JasonTheDeveloper
// Created          : 09-07-2020
//
// Last Modified By : dannygar
// Last Modified On : 09-07-2020
// ***********************************************************************
// <copyright file="AudioProcessor.cs" company="Microsoft">
//     Copyright ©  2020
// </copyright>
// <summary></summary>
// ***********************************************************************
using NAudio.Wave;
using RecordingBot.Model.Constants;
using RecordingBot.Services.Contract;
using RecordingBot.Services.ServiceSetup;
using RecordingBot.Services.Util;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RecordingBot.Services.Media
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class AudioProcessor.
    /// Implements the <see cref="RecordingBot.Services.Util.BufferBase{RecordingBot.Services.Media.SerializableAudioMediaBuffer}" />
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="RecordingBot.Services.Util.BufferBase{RecordingBot.Services.Media.SerializableAudioMediaBuffer}" />
    public class AudioProcessor : BufferBase<SerializableAudioMediaBuffer>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The writers
        /// </summary>
        readonly Dictionary<string, WaveFileWriter> _writers = new Dictionary<string, WaveFileWriter>();

        /// <summary>
        /// The processor identifier
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string _processorId = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// The settings
        /// </summary>
        private readonly AzureSettings _settings;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="AudioProcessor" /> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="settings">The settings.</param>
        public AudioProcessor(IAzureSettings settings)
        {
            _processorId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            _settings = (AzureSettings)settings;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Processes the specified data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">The data.</param>
        protected override async Task Process(SerializableAudioMediaBuffer data)
        {
            if (data.Timestamp == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), BotConstants.DefaultOutputFolder, _settings.MediaFolder, _processorId);

            // First, write all audio buffer, unless the data.IsSilence is checked for true, into the all speakers buffer
            var all = "all";
            var all_writer = _writers.ContainsKey(all) ? _writers[all] : InitialiseWavFileWriter(path, all);

            if (data.Buffer != null)
            {
                // Buffers are saved to disk even when there is silence.
                // If you do not want this to happen, check if data.IsSilence == true.
                await all_writer.WriteAsync(data.Buffer, 0, data.Buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            if (data.SerializableUnmixedAudioBuffers != null)
            {
                foreach (var s in data.SerializableUnmixedAudioBuffers)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.AdId) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.DisplayName))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var id = s.AdId;

                    var writer = _writers.ContainsKey(id) ? _writers[id] : InitialiseWavFileWriter(path, id);

                    // Write audio buffer into the WAV file for individual speaker
                    await writer.WriteAsync(s.Buffer, 0, s.Buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    // Write audio buffer into the WAV file for all speakers
                    await all_writer.WriteAsync(s.Buffer, 0, s.Buffer.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);

                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialises the wav file writer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rootFolder">The root folder.</param>
        /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
        /// <returns>WavFileWriter.</returns>
        private WaveFileWriter InitialiseWavFileWriter(string rootFolder, string id)
        {
            var path = AudioFileUtils.CreateFilePath(rootFolder, $"{id}.wav");

            // Initialize the Wave Format using the default PCM 16bit 16K supported by Teams audio settings
            var writer = new WaveFileWriter(path, new WaveFormat(
                rate: AudioConstants.DefaultSampleRate,
                bits: AudioConstants.DefaultBits,
                channels: AudioConstants.DefaultChannels));

            _writers.Add(id, writer);

            return writer;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finalises the wav writing and returns a list of all the files created
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>System.String.</returns>
        public async Task<string> Finalise()
        {
            //drain the un-processed buffers on this object
            while (Buffer.Count > 0)
            {
                await Task.Delay(200);
            }

            var archiveFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), BotConstants.DefaultOutputFolder, _settings.MediaFolder, _processorId, $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.zip");

            try
            {
                using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(archiveFile))
                {
                    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
                    {
                        // drain all the writers
                        foreach (var writer in _writers.Values)
                        {
                            var localFiles = new List<string>();
                            var localArchive = archive; //protect the closure below
                            var localFileName = writer.Filename;
                            localFiles.Add(writer.Filename);
                            await writer.FlushAsync();
                            writer.Dispose();

                            // Is Resampling and/or mono to stereo conversion required?
                            if (_settings.AudioSettings.WavSettings != null)
                            {
                                // The resampling is required
                                localFiles.Add(AudioFileUtils.ResampleAudio(localFileName, _settings.AudioSettings.WavSettings, _settings.IsStereo));
                            }
                            else if (_settings.IsStereo) // Is Stereo audio required?
                            {
                                // Convert mono WAV to stereo
                                localFiles.Add(AudioFileUtils.ConvertToStereo(localFileName));
                            }

                            // Remove temporary saved local WAV file from the disk
                            foreach (var localFile in localFiles)
                            {
                                await Task.Run(() =>
                                {
                                    var fInfo = new FileInfo(localFile);
                                    localArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(localFile, fInfo.Name, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                                    File.Delete(localFile);
                                }).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                await End();
            }

            return archiveFile;
        }
    }
}
`

I request you to please help us on this. We need to get video from team-recording-bot and save it to local in.zip file and also to s3 bucket. Please, Please help us on this.
```

Comment: I am also working on recording bot. Can you please confirm if SSL certificate is required for local testing?

Comment: Yes. You need to use ngrok pro subscription and register a domain on it. after that you need to generate ssl certificate on it.